# Database connection error when IP address is specified

Tags: mysql, hibernate

this is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.23:3306/meili_s?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>


    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection">30</property>

    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3600</property>  <!-- seconds -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property> <!-- seconds -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1;</property>

    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

The problem is that when the "hibernate.connection.url" has the IP address (of my VM) like just "localhost" all works but when it is an IP number (except for 127.0.0.1) i get this error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:78)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
... 45 more
```

Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1319)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:557)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:477)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:525)
    ... 48 more

have you ever had some issue?

thanks lot in advance.

Comment: try on mysql- grant all on *.* to '<username>'@<'ip'> identified by <password> and then check

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but just double-checking. Can you connect to the remote DB with the above credentials using the command line mysql or MySQL Workbench, etc, from the machine you are running the java code on? My bet is that you are missing the needed permissions on your remote DB to connect as root from other than localhost or have some other issue related to simple connectivity to the DB independent of Hibernate.

Comment: i made it already something like -- grant all privileges on *.* to 'root'@'192.168.0.23' identified by 'pwd'; -- but same problem:(

Comment: i solved with http://stackoverflow.com/a/9747068/2824823 !